# How can I fix this oracle error?

Tags: oracle-database

When I execute this command it won't work. Why am I getting this error? What can I do to fix this? Thanks!

```
$ grant read,write on directory <SID>_DATA_PUMP_DIR to system;
$ grant read,write on directory <SID>_DATA_PUMP_DIR to system
                                                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01749: you may not GRANT/REVOKE privileges to/from yourself
```

Comment: [Database Administrators - Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) is more suitable for your question.

Comment: Hmmm, @Akina, that site [advertises](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) it _"is for those needing expert answers to **advanced** database-related questions"_ (emphasis mine). But it's surely off-topic here indeed.

Comment: Are you logged in to SQL*Plus as the `system` user? if not, try to switch to it using `conn` command.

Answer (score 1):

I think error itself explains it. You have created the DBA_DIRECTORY using system user and trying to provide a grant to itself(Owner).

ORA-01749: you may not GRANT/REVOKE privileges to/from yourself

I think there is no need to run grant command.